# React-router create and delete browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I want to redirect to last 2nd route in my react app when user go backs from a particular route but I'm not able to find a solution.
Anybody who can help??

I want this when user clicks on back button but not when component unmount.

Comment: i think you can use useNavigate and navigate(-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `useHistory` hook.

First, import it:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

Second, call it and save its return value in a constant:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

Then call the `goBack()` method to go once back, or the `go(n)` to go back `n` times in the stack history:

```
history.go(-2);
```

You can read more in the official docs:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history

---

If you are using version 6, use the `useNavigate` hook instead:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// ...
const navigate = useNavigate();
// ...
navigate(-2);
```

You can read more here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate